# LINQ to NETEZZA

Tags: linq, netezza

Does anyone know if it is possible to use LINQ to query a NETEZZA back-end?

**Update:** I've tried both the ODBC and OLEDB Netezza drivers, but neither work. Both give a "The selected object(s) use an unsupported data source" error.

Comment: VS2010 RC?  I found I could use SQL 2000 as a datasource in VS2010 Beta 1 and 2, but not RC.  Maybe the same results for you.

Comment: No - just using VS2008 as it happens

Comment: Another possibility would be to load the data into datasets and use LINQ that way - but is going to be way painful for me, because then I lose all the freebies that LINQ2SQL gives you with it's automatic ORM...

Comment: Did you try a linked server (i.e. through SQL Server to NETEZZA)? I don't know if that would work, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, but we'll give it a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've figured out a way to do this - kinda.

We've created a custom Data Class in the DBML file that reflects the structure of the stored procedure. We then use a stored procedure on Netezza (executed via a table adapter and the Netezza OLE DB driver) to file the class.

Our DAL (data access layer) pretty much just exposes the classes in the DBML to the BLL (business logic layer), so the data class looks and behaves the same as any other LINQ class.

We can't do updates, but that's not important in this instance.